# How to dump SQL Server Express schema to github?

Tags: sql-server

At the moment I'm using SQL Server Management Studio and stored procedures to execute all my API calls. I'm wondering where could I get started if I wanted to transfer the schema and queries within my stored procedures to github. Thanks!